# How to do this (coded in java) in python/jython?

Tags: java, python, for-loop, jython

I'm still learning python/jython, so sorry if I ask silly questions.

I have this for loop in java, but I have no idea how to code it in Python/Jython, since it insists using "in"...

```
for(String effectString : config.getStringList("string.list") {
// Do something
```

I tried:

```
for effectString = config.getStringList("string.list"):
```

and

```
for effectString in config.getStringList("string.list"):
```

but then I realised that I didn't defined effectString and, actually, effectString is config.getStringList("string.list")...

Thanks for explanation in advance, Amar!

Comment: Your last example is syntactically correct.

Comment: In Python you don't need to define a variable before you use it in a `for` statement, so assuming `config.getStringList("stringlist")` is a generator of some sort, then you're all set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your following syntax is correct if `config.getStringList("string.list")` returns a collection.

```
for effectString in config.getStringList("string.list"):
```

Syntax [For loops](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop)

Comment: It looks like it was my mistake, probably I missed something while testing that, anyway, thanks for explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop in python to iterate over `iterables`.

Iterables can be a `list`, `dict`, `generator` objects, etc.

For example

```
>>> for num in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
...     print num    
1
2
3
4
>>> my_nums = ("0", "1", "2")
>>> for num in my_nums:
...     print num
0
1
2
>>> my_classes = [int, float, abs, str]
>>> for cls in my_classes:
...     print cls
<type 'int'>
<type 'float'>
<built-in function abs>
<type 'str'>
```

For more details, have a look at the [Python Docs](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop).

Answer (score 0):

This syntax:

```
for effectString in config.getStringList("string.list"):
```

is correct. When using `for` loops in Python you implicitly create a local variable.

In some languages, `for (i=0; i<10; i++)` might be how a `for` loop would look. There, you explicitly initialize the variable `i`, to be used in the body of the loop. In Python, `for something in iterable` creates the local variable `something`.

It is also worth noting that the variable persists after the loop is finished:

```
>>> for i in range(10):
        pass
>>> print(i)
9
```